# Java reactor and variable scope

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am trying to get my head around variable propagation using reactor. I have a function as follow where I am trying to pass a variable named requestName from outside the map as follow:

```
  public Mono<ResponseEntity<? extends Object>> myFunction(
      final Object request, final String requestName) {

    return this.client
        .create(request)
        .exchangeToMono(
            response -> {
              final HttpStatus status = response.statusCode();
              return response
                  .bodyToMono(String.class)
                  .defaultIfEmpty(StringUtils.EMPTY)
                  .map(
                      body -> {
                        if (status.is2xxSuccessful()) {
                          log.info("{}", requestName);
                          return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
                        } else {
                          return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(null);
                        }
                      });
            })
        .onErrorResume(ex -> Mono.just(buildErrorFromException(requestName, ex)));
  }
```

or another example would be:

```
      String myvar = "test"
      return this.
        .login()
        .flatMap(
            response ->
                this.myservice(myvar))
        .flatMap(
            response2 ->
                this.myservice2(myvar))
```

Is it appropriate ? Or would i need to wrap this function around a Mono.deferContextual and apply a contextView ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: that works, java does support clojures, what i am wondering though is why you parse the body first then you check the status code. Move your if-status up. Also you should be using exchangeToMono instead read the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-exchange

Comment: Thanks a lot @Toerktumlare for your response! There is really very few information about variable scope in reactor doc! I actually just simplified my function but it is basically for logging purposes

Comment: correction of my previous comment, java does NOT support clojures. So the provided way does work. Variable scop has nothing to do with reactor. It has with java and lambdas so there should not be any information about it in the webflux docs. Read the java language lambda docs